# django complex postgres query parsing

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

The user in my frontend can submit an arbitrary nested query string on the id of my model like so

```py
querystring="(driver = 1 AND routes = 3) OR ( driver = 2 AND weather = 1 )"
```

I want to use djangos complex Q function to query this string in the backend, meaning I need to turn *querystring* into something like

```py
criterion = \
(Q(detail__drivers=1) & Q(routes =3) ) | (Q(detail__driver=2) & Q(detail__weather=1) )
```

in order to be able to filter using

```
self.queryset.filter(criterion)
```

But how can I automatically translate the string into the criterion while maintaining the parentheses structure?

Comment: you need to write a parser that can understand grouping by (), AND and OR. Look at [this](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/simpleBool.py)

Comment: why do you want to use `Q`, is it not possible to simply do `self.queryset.filter(detail__drivers__id__in=[1], routes__id__in=[3], detail__driver__id__in=[2], detail__weather__id__in=[1])`??

Comment: you will loose the AND/OR logic this way

Comment: Not sure why you're using `__in` when all the values are single. Why not `detail__drivers=1 & routes__id=3` etc?

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right of course

Comment: @benito_h oh sorry, didn't see the pipe `|` symbol lol, I thought it's all `&`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
self.queryset.filter(Q(detail__drivers=1, routes =3) |(Q(detail__driver=2, detail__weather=1))
```

Comment: this does not answer the question I'm afraid

Comment: Ok, so in this case you can use Raw-sql-queries with django